# Filtering movielist JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am trying to filter the movie list when i compare the category with the value of `select`. But I am having some issues specially with the movies that contains more than one category.

How do I work around that?

And can you tell me how to return data in asynchronus function?

```
window.addEventListener("load", setup);
var select = document.querySelector("select");

function setup() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'data/data.json', true);

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

      var output = '';
      var genre = '<option> ' + "-- Select Genre --" + ' </option>';

      for (var i = 0; i < data.movies.length; i++) {
        output += '<ul>' +
          '<li> Title: ' + data.movies[i].title + '</li>' +
          '<li> Category: ' + data.movies[i].categories + '</li>' +
          '</ul>';
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < data.categories.length; i++) {
        genre += '<option> ' + data.categories[i] + ' </option>';
      }

      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
      document.getElementById('selection').innerHTML = genre;

      select.addEventListener('change', filter);

      function filter() {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.categories.length; i++) {
          if (data.movies[i].categories == select.value) {
            alert(2)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  xhr.onerror = function() {
    console.log("req");
  }
  xhr.send();
}
```

I have now changed it, so the category and movie is generated in different loops, but I still can't seem to add `class` to the `ul` elements when the category is selected I only want to show movies that goes by that category

My [json](/questions/tagged/json)where you can see how the data is setup in an object:

```
{
  "movies": [{
    "title": "Mad Max",
    "categories": "action"
  }, {
    "title": "Willow",
    "categories": "action,fantasy"
  }, {
    "title": "Alien",
    "categories": "action,sci-fi"
  }, {
    "title": "Silence of the lambs",
    "categories": "thriller"
  }, {
    "title": "The Ring",
    "categories": "horror"
  }, {
    "title": "Gone with the wind",
    "categories": "drama"
  }, {
    "title": "Lion King",
    "categories": "animation, family"
  }, {
    "title": "Jumanji",
    "categories": "action,fantasy, family"
  }, {
    "title": "Heat",
    "categories": "action,thriller"
  }, {
    "title": "Blade runner",
    "categories": "action,sci-fi"
  }],
  "categories": ["action", "sci-fi", "drama", "thriller", "horror", "fantasy", "family", "animation"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you'll need a helper function to performs [**`XMLHttpRequest`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) properly in order to return data asynchronously. For example:

```
var newXHR = null;

function sendXHR(options, callback) {
  newXHR = new XMLHttpRequest() || new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  options.contentType = options.contentType || "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  newXHR.open(options.type, options.url, true);
  newXHR.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", options.contentType);
  newXHR.send(options.data);
  newXHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.status === 200 && this.readyState === 4) {
      callback(this.response);
    }
  };
}
```

In this example, we show how to configure the [**`XMLHttpRequest`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) object to perform asynchronous requests and assign the response in a callback function.

**Usage:**

```
sendXHR({
  url: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dannyjhonston/288a0555179f379008e901d9d5f034a3/raw/03519253848040cd8c7d68dceb0e5a53755e5f52/movies.json",
  type: "GET"
}, function(response) {
  console.log(response); // Contains data from the url.
  // Performs other operations with the response.
});
```

With the given response, fill the categories with this function:

```
function fillCategories(data) {
  var selection = document.getElementById("selection"), html = "", len = data.categories.length;
  html += "<option>-- Select Genre --</option>";
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    html += "<option value=\"";
    html += data.categories[i];
    html += "\">";
    html += data.categories[i];
    html += "</option>";
  }
  selection.innerHTML = html; // Render the html.
  selection.onchange = function() { // When the selection field is changed call the printOutput function.
    printOutput(this.value); // this.value is the selected genre.
  };
}
```

With the **selected genre**, fill the output with this function:

```
function printOutput(genre) {
  var result = data.movies.filter(function(x) {
      return x.categories.indexOf(genre) > -1;
    }), output = document.getElementById("output"), len = result.length, html = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    html += "<li>";
    html += result[i].title;
    html += "</li>";
  }
  output.innerHTML = html;
}
```

In the previous function, I'm using [**`Array.prototype.filter()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to return a new array with the movies that correspond to the selected category, by using `x.categories.indexOf (genre) > -1;`.

Something like this:

```js
(function() {
  var newXHR = null; // Once initialized with the XMLHttpRequest object, you can use the abort() method from anywhere in the code.
  var data = {}; // This variable is declared in the global scope.

  function sendXHR(options, callback) {
    newXHR = new XMLHttpRequest() || new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    options.contentType = options.contentType || "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    newXHR.open(options.type, options.url, true);
    newXHR.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", options.contentType);
    newXHR.send(options.data);
    newXHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.status === 200 && this.readyState === 4) {
        callback(this.response);
      }
    };
  }
  sendXHR({
    url: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dannyjhonston/288a0555179f379008e901d9d5f034a3/raw/03519253848040cd8c7d68dceb0e5a53755e5f52/movies.json",
    type: "GET"
  }, function(response) {
    data = JSON.parse(response);
    fillCategories(data);
  });

  function printOutput(genre) {
    var result = data.movies.filter(function(x) {
        return x.categories.indexOf(genre) > -1;
      }), output = document.getElementById("output"), len = result.length, html = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      html += "<li>";
      html += result[i].title;
      html += "</li>";
    }
    output.innerHTML = html;
  }

  function fillCategories(data) {
    var selection = document.getElementById("selection"),
      html = "", len = data.categories.length;
    html += "<option>-- Select Genre --</option>";
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      html += "<option value=\"";
      html += data.categories[i];
      html += "\">";
      html += data.categories[i];
      html += "</option>";
    }
    selection.innerHTML = html;
    selection.onchange = function() {
      printOutput(this.value);
    };
  }
}());
```

```html
<select id="selection"></select>
<ul id="output"></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks i will take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Yo have some errors in you logic.

1. the loop is associated to movies.length with i variable but you are trying to use it to get categories index as well.

Try to split you logic to manage categories and then movies.I mean create 2 separated loops...

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.movies.length; i++)
{
  //movies html generation
}

for(var i = 0; i < data.categories.length; i++)
{
  //categories html generation
}
```

2 your movies contains categories properties as string and you are trying it as array.

So inside movies loop, do something like this...

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.movies.length; i++)
{
   data.movies[i].categories = data.movies[i].categories.split(',');
   //movies html generation
}
```

Notice You can use the navigator developer tool to debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var movieList = {
    "movies": [{
        "title": "Mad Max",
        "categories": "action"
    }, {
        "title": "Willow",
        "categories": "action,fantasy"
    }, {
        "title": "Alien",
        "categories": "action,sci-fi"
    }, {
        "title": "Silence of the lambs",
        "categories": "thriller"
    }, {
        "title": "The Ring",
        "categories": "horror"
    }, {
        "title": "Gone with the wind",
        "categories": "drama"
    }, {
        "title": "Lion King",
        "categories": "animation, family"
    }, {
        "title": "Jumanji",
        "categories": "action,fantasy, family"
    }, {
        "title": "Heat",
        "categories": "action,thriller"
    }, {
        "title": "Blade runner",
        "categories": "action,sci-fi"
    }],
    "categories": ["action", "sci-fi", "drama", "thriller", "horror", "fantasy", "family", "animation"]
}

var movieArray = movieList.movies.map(function(a) {
 return {
   "title": a.title,
    "categories": a.categories.split(",")
  }
})

console.log(movieArray);

console.log(movieArray.filter(function(a) {
    return a.categories.includes("thriller")
}));
```

Hope this helps you with your data formatting.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. but I cant use that, it has to be used from the JSON file... Since it is a test I have to do

Comment: Yeah. If your json is in the same format, save your json to a variable and work on that data. So movieList.categories will be in your options and then with the reworked data, you can filter them out.

Comment: And i do that liked it is shown here ?... I cant make variables inside the JSON file ?

Comment: Wait.. Are you creating JSON data or getting JSON data and populate it on the UI?

Comment: I am getting the data from a JSON file... and then populate it in the UI

Comment: Cool. So when you get the data from json, store it in a variable and then work on that data. Thats what I did.